# How to retrieve plain text from .doc files using Python?

Tags: python, ms-word

How can I pull out plain text from a .doc file? (MSDoc 97-03) I'm able to pull out plain text from .docx but not .doc

I've got an almost working code for .doc, which goes like this

```
        if file.endswith('.doc'):
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
            doc = app.Documents.Open(fullpath)
            docText = (doc.Content)
            print docText
            app.Quit()
```

The problem is, whenever I run this code, I get both the plain text and an error which goes like this:

This is a testing file to test the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IdaLim\Desktop\MyTestCode\FileIO.py", line 76, in <module> doc =                  

  app.Documents.Open(fullpath) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
  packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in __getattr__ raise 
  AttributeError("%s.%s"% (self._username_, attr)) AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents
```

On top of that, if the plain text includes non-alphabet characters like "!@#$%", the program will not output the plain text, and gives an error that says incompatible Unicode or something.

Do you know of any functioning code that allow almost perfect retrieval of plain text from .doc files?

Comment: win32com seems to be the right direction, here is the [object model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515.aspx) from Microsoft, this might help you interface with the objects in the document. Additionally you might want to check [goermezer.de python scripting](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/category/7/86/192/) for sample code to do things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found the workaround for this solution.

I converted the .doc files to .txt files successfully, with all the special characters and encodings converted to .txt format. The codes are given below. I guess what you can do (if you need to) is to read the newly created text files and then store it in your python program's variables. From there you can do any nitty-gritty stuff you want with it.

```
import win32com.client 
import os
import re
rootdir ='C:\Users\IdaLim\Desktop\docs'     
try:
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    app.Visible = True
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(*[subdir, file])
            if file.endswith(".doc"):
                out_name = file.replace("doc", r"txt")
                in_file = os.path.abspath(rootdir + "\\" + file)
                out_file = os.path.abspath(rootdir + "\\" + out_name)
                doc = app.Documents.Open(in_file)
                content = doc.Content.Text
                print 'Exporting', out_file
                doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=7)
                doc.Close()
except Exception, e:
    print e
finally:
    app.Quit()
```